# How to change the date formate of objects of NSMutablearray which contains dates?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsdateformatter

I have one `NSMutableArray` which contain dates

for example :

```
 NSMutableArray *arrDates = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"22/07/2042","05/04/2015","22/08/2015","22/08/2015","22/09/2015","22/09/2015", nil];
```

I want to change the formate of that date in `MM/dd/yyyy` formate which is in `dd/MM/yyyy` formate.
and after changing the formate i want to store in another `NSMutableArray`.
How can I do that??

Comment: this would sure be easier if you simply saved dates in your array as `NSDate` objects instead of as strings :-)

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Yes you are absolutely right but my array is not static i'm getting  this array in response of web service so i want to change that without taking NSDate as a object of array.

Comment: that doesn't make any difference either u have static or  dynamic array. You can still convert into nsdates and store them in your array.

Comment: ok buddy :)   Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to keep a single array of `NSDate` objects. `NSDate` represents a date irrespective of format. To obtain a formatted `NSString` from an `NSDate`, you can use `NSDateFormatter`.

```
NSDate *date = self.dates[index];
self.dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"dd-MM-yy";
NSString *dateString = [self.dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

`NSDateFormatter` can also convert from `NSString` to `NSDate`. So when you parse the strings from your web service, you should convert them to `NSDate` objects for storage:

```
NSString *dateString = stringFromServer;
self.dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"dd-MM-yy";
NSDate *date = [self.dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```